# codeigniter join query, display data to view

Tags: php, mysql, function, codeigniter, join

im new to codeigniter & php, and i have some question about join() function.
i have this model:

```
public function get_categorie()
{       
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('foxCategory');
        $this->db->join('foxAnnunci', 'foxCategory.id = foxAnnunci.id_foxCategory');

        $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

this controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['category']= $this->annunci_model->get_categorie();
    $data['annunci'] = $this->annunci_model->get_annunci();
    $data['titolo'] = 'Elenco annunci';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('annunci/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

and this view

```
<h2><?php echo $value['titolo'] ?></h2>
<div id="main">
      <code>Data di creazione: <?php echo $value['creato_il'] ?></code><br />
    <?php echo $value['descrizione'] ?>
</div>
<p><a href="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">Guarda annuncio || <p><?php echo $category['category']['titolo'] ?></p></a></p>
```

i want to display the name of category as link (classic for blog category function), but this code show nothing, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is you're not returning anything from the model...Should be `return $this->db->get();`

Comment: thank you man, but i have the problem in my view, the codeigniter say me

 Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array in /var/www/foxiness/application/views/annunci/index.php on line 13

Comment: Sorry, you need to return a result in order to...have a result! Like `return $this->db->get()->result_array()` in order to have the results as an array

Comment: i see with the print_r() the value of array, and i understand the logic! thank you man

the question is, how can i print the 'category' link each post?